# where do I find the xml.dom python package for the python-2.6.0-8.9.28 and I have a suse/x86_64 version of Linux version

Tags: python, xml, linux, unix

Please if somebody could help me find python-2.6.0-8.9.28 xml.dom package. Please, help

Comment: Google would be a better place than SO!

Comment: How did this question get an upvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

everytime you are not sure about a python package, you can try this:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi

However, I'm using python 2.6 on linux and it has xml.dom. I'm not sure, but I think it is already included:

http://docs.python.org/release/2.6/library/index.html