# ImportError: No module named dom

Tags: python, xml

I am using python 2.7.8. i have done lot of search and failed to solve this problem. I meet these type of links for packages:

[where do I find the xml.dom python package for the python-2.6.0-8.9.28 and I have a suse/x86_64 version of Linux version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027337/where-do-i-find-the-xml-dom-python-package-for-the-python-2-6-0-8-9-28-and-i-hav)

but failed as well(i tried to implement 2.7.8 not 2.6 by using above link).

I am using the code from:
[Python XML parsing from website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16441823/python-xml-parsing-from-website)

Basically i am trying to get out xml and here is the code:

```
from xml.dom import minidom
import urllib

url_str = 'http://www.newyorkfed.org/markets/omo/dmm/fftoXML.cfm?type=daily'
xml_str = urllib.urlopen(xml_str).read()
xmldoc = minidom.parseString(xml_str)

obs_values = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('base:OBS_VALUE')
# prints the first base:OBS_VALUE it finds
print obs_values[0].firstChild.nodeValue

# prints the second base:OBS_VALUE it finds
print obs_values[1].firstChild.nodeValue

# prints all base:OBS_VALUE in the XML doc
for obs_val in obs_values:
    print obs_val.firstChild.nodeValue
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\python\s\fyp\xml.py", line 1, in <module>
    from xml.dom import minidom
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\python\s\fyp\xml.py", line 1, in <module>
    from xml.dom import minidom
ImportError: No module named dom
```

Comment: can you import `import xml` ?

Comment: if i write import xml it gives me error : NameError: name 'xml_str' is not defined

Comment: What is the file located at `C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\python\s\fyp\xml.py`?  It looks like its shadowing the stdlib module.

Comment: xml.py is my file name

Comment: it is in separate folder on desktop

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check like this

```
import xml
print(xml.__file__)
```

Then check whether it is picking from python modules you are expecting.

Also check whether any other `xml.py` in corresponding folder you are working with. If any `rename` it.

Also change this.

```
xml_str = urllib.urlopen(url_str).read()
```

Comment: is that you saying? import xml
import urllib

url_str = 'http://www.newyorkfed.org/markets/omo/dmm/fftoXML.cfm?type=daily'
xml_str = urllib.urlopen(xml_str).read()
xmldoc = minidom.parseString(xml_str)

obs_values = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('base:OBS_VALUE')
# prints the first base:OBS_VALUE it finds
print xml.obs_values[0].firstChild.nodeValue

# prints the second base:OBS_VALUE it finds
print xml.obs_values[1].firstChild.nodeValue

# prints all base:OBS_VALUE in the XML doc
for obs_val in obs_values:
    print xml.obs_val.firstChild.nodeValue

Comment: it is for checking only, now its clear.Please rename your `xml.py` to `myxml.py`.Rename your file and continue without edit your program.like `from xml.dom import minidom`

Comment: i did rename but still same

Comment: what same? no module? try remove xml.pyc

Comment: and in python27 folder there are xmlbuilder.pyc, xmldocs.pyc,xmlrpclib.pyc... and in my destop folder there is no such file

Comment: Still no module error? Are you trying in ipterpreter or ipython? then restart it

Comment: after delete xml.pyc , restart shell and try like my answer above.You can see which file is importing.Skip all other lines.Just the above lines.

Comment: i restarted and still result is zero . like u asked me : import xml print xml._file_ gives me Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\python\s\fyp\p.py", line 1, in <module>
    import xml
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\python\s\fyp\xml.py", line 1, in <module>
    from xml.dom import minidom
ImportError: No module named dom

Comment: You are still didnt delete this file or rename it, `C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\python\s\fyp\xml.py` or `C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\python\s\fyp\xml.pyc`

Comment: i have renamed my file name as p.py and deleted xml.pyc 100 times but i astonished having such more suggestion did nt did any work

Comment: Complete answer: Create new folder `myfolder`, create new file `myxml.py` and copy all your code to it. run

Comment: yea did but new error arrives NameError: name 'minidom' is not defined. and now wt is this??

Comment: change top line `import xml` to `from xml.dom import minidom`

Comment: i did but it is highlighting this line xmldoc = mindom.parseString(xml_str)

Comment: how are you executing this program. `python myxml.py` ?

Comment: file name is p.py and then pressing F5 simply.

Comment: it is taking the link as u can see in my old above code and try generating xml

Comment: I had named my sourcefile xml.py, which python treated as the source file for the import. Renaming my source file to parse_xml.py and deleting xml.pyc from the project directory fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 5):

You named your module `xml.py`. Don't do that, it is masking the built-in package. Python is finding your script, not the built-in `xml` package. Your `xml` script doesn't have a `dom` sub-package so the import fails.

You can see this in your traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\python\s\fyp\xml.py", line 1, in <module>
    from xml.dom import minidom
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\python\s\fyp\xml.py", line 1, in <module>
    from xml.dom import minidom
ImportError: No module named dom
```

Your script is initially imported as the `__main__` module, so the `xml.dom` import line imports the script itself again, now as `xml`, which is why your script line appears *twice* in that traceback.

Rename your script to something else; you may have to delete a remaining `xml.pyc` file if one was left behind.

Next you have a typo in your code:

```
xml_str = urllib.urlopen(xml_str).read()
#                        ^^^^^^^
```

That should probably be using `url_str` instead.

Comment: i ve changed the name of my file now as "p.py" and did changes like u said: url_str = 'http://www.newyorkfed.org/markets/omo/dmm/fftoXML.cfm?type=daily'
xml_str = urllib.urlopen(url_str).read()
xmldoc = minidom.parseString(xml_str)  but still same result....

Comment: @dellpk: What is the result here now? A different error?

Comment: @dellpk: is there a `xml.pyc` file still? If so, delete that too.

Comment: in python27 folder there are xmlbuilder.pyc, xmldocs.pyc,xmlrpclib.pyc... and in my destop folder there is no such file

Comment: @dellpk: look closely at the traceback produced. If it still says `C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\python\s\fyp\xml.py` or `C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\python\s\fyp\xml.pyc` in there you know where to look to clean this up.

Comment: @dellpk: and do restart Python!

Comment: is xml.pyc is compiled form? if this is then i did delete that one. but same error.

Comment: i always deletes other files which are of no use. but i dont know how it is not happening

Comment: @dellpk: yes, the `.pyc` file is the cached compiled bytecode. If you are getting the same error still, look closely at the traceback. Or use `import xml; print xml.__file__` to see what is being imported instead of the standard library package. You could easily still have another `xml.py` somewhere else. I cannot see what errors you are continuing to get at this time.

Comment: @dellpk: no, the `xml.__file__` attribute is the filename from which the module was loaded. If you continue to get this same error, Python is continuing to load the wrong file when you ask to import `xml.dom`. That is why we are trying to help you print that value so you can figure out what is being imported.

Comment: yeah i tested with the one u saying e.g import xml

print(xml.__file__) but it still giving me the same error

Comment: @dellpk: Your `xml` script itself imports `xml`, so it'll throw that error. The traceback is not giving you any hints as to what filenames are being imported? Each line in the traceback that starts with `File` at the start. You don't need to use `easy_setup dom` here **at all**.

Comment: i renamed my file name here is the code all: import xml
import urllib

url_str = 'http://www.newyorkfed.org/markets/omo/dmm/fftoXML.cfm?type=daily'
xml_str = urllib.urlopen(url_str).read()
xmldoc = minidom.parseString(xml_str)

obs_values = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('base:OBS_VALUE')
# prints the first base:OBS_VALUE it finds
print obs_values[0].firstChild.nodeValue

# prints the second base:OBS_VALUE it finds
print obs_values[1].firstChild.nodeValue

# prints all base:OBS_VALUE in the XML doc
for obs_val in obs_values:
    print obs_val.firstChild.nodeValue

Comment: Yes, that code works, I already tested that. That's not the issue. If you are having the same error again and again, then Python is still importing the old file. That means there is either a `xml.py` or `xml.pyc` file in place somewhere there should not be, or you haven't restarted Python (IDLE counts as Python too).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73830/discussion-between-dell-pk-and-martijn-pieters).

Answer (score 1):

This is a recent issue in PyCharm 2020.1.  The problem is already reported in `https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-41791`

There have proposed the following workaround until the issue is fixed:

> Replace xml directory in
> <INSTALLATION_FOLDER>\plugins\python-ce)\helpers\typeshed\stdlib\2and3
> with xml from
> https://github.com/python/typeshed/tree/master/stdlib/2and3/xml

After performing this, go to PyCharm and Code -> Code Cleanup. After the clean up is completed, restart PyCharm for the new settings to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to

```
from xml.dom import minidom
```

but you can't call your own file xml.py (for this same reason don't call it random.py math.py etc)